# HashMaps getting different Hash Codes for same string and province

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I am parsing 3 different Json arrays for different int values. The following are links to the 3 arrays(Formatting wouldn't let me hyperlink for some reason). 
https://api.covid19api.com/country/canada/status/deaths/live?from=2020-05-01T00:00:00Z&to=2020-05-02T00:00:00Z
 https://api.covid19api.com/country/canada/status/recovered/live?from=2020-05-01T00:00:00Z&to=2020-05-02T00:00:00Z
 https://api.covid19api.com/country/canada/status/confirmed/live?from=2020-05-01T00:00:00Z&to=2020-05-02T00:00:00Z

I need to write this into a DB which I have properly implemented, but my Map implementation is wrong. As of now, I know the the arrays are the same size since they cover the same date range. I am looping over each array and creating 3 separate hash-maps. The key to the hash-map is a custom structure i created which is a pair of strings , and the value is the integer that I am interested in. i'm doing it this way since I know, or I believe upon inspecting the Arrays, that all 3 Maps will contain the same key-set, hence the same Hashcode, so when I call .get(key) on one array, i will also be able to get the values associated with the same key (date and province) from the other Maps. Accessing the other hash-maps using a key value returns null, however, my unit tests for equals and Hashcode are succeeding. Some help as to what is causing this would be lovely. (I know there is a typo in the spelling of my custom class name, but its consistent through ought and I haven't refactored yet).  I'm assuming its an issue with my hashcode in my custom structure

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= arrayRecovered.length()-1; i++) {  // To loop over all json objects in the array and grab the required values needed. This is the loop for the recovered keyword

        String provinceRecovered = arrayRecovered.getJSONObject(i).getString("Province");
        String dateRecovered = arrayRecovered.getJSONObject(i).getString("Date");// 
        // of case should be on

        myStrucutre recoveredKey = new myStrucutre(dateRecovered, provinceRecovered);
        recoveredMap.put(recoveredKey, arrayRecovered.getJSONObject(i).getInt("Cases")); // Putting the value associated with the number of recovered cases in the province on the returned date.

        String provinceConfirmed = arrayConfirmed.getJSONObject(i).getString("Province"); //Getting province associated confirmed case at place i
        String dateConfirmed = arrayConfirmed.getJSONObject(i).getString("Date");
        myStrucutre confirmedKey = new myStrucutre(dateConfirmed, provinceConfirmed);
        confirmedMap.put(confirmedKey, arrayConfirmed.getJSONObject(i).getInt("Cases"));


        String provinceDeath = arrayDeaths.getJSONObject(i).getString("Province");
        String dateDeath = arrayDeaths.getJSONObject(i).getString("Date");


        myStrucutre deathKey = new myStrucutre(dateDeath, provinceDeath);
        deathsMap.put(deathKey, arrayDeaths.getJSONObject(i).getInt("Cases"));
    }
```

// This is my own data structure I am using to implement the key value for HASH MAP and HASH TABLES. I want keys to be equal when the string representing the date and province are the same.
    // So I had to override hashcode and equals to make sure of this.

```
private final String date;
private final String province;

public myStrucutre(String date, String province) {
    this.date = date;
    this.province = province;

}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public String getProvince() {
    return province;
}

@Override // Want to make sure the Strings are equal then the keys are equal
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = super.hashCode();
    hash = 89 * hash + (date != null ? date.hashCode() : 0);
    hash = 89 * hash + (province != null ? province.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    myStrucutre thing = (myStrucutre) o;

    if (province != null ? !province.equals(thing.province) : thing.province != null) return false;

    return date != null ? date.equals(thing.date) : thing.date == null;
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you taking super.hascode() into considération? This will make différent hascode for equal objects.

Answer (score 1):

You say *“I know, or I believe upon inspecting the Arrays, that all 3 Maps will contain the same key-set, hence the same Hashcode”*

What you want is that the `hashcode` should depend SOLELY on the key fields - but that is not how you have implemented it, because of this line :

```
int hash = super.hashCode();
```

You start your hashcode with the super’s hashcode (which Is a different value for different objects), which means the eventual result also includes this value - and will therefore be different for different objects.

Just start instead with :

```
int hash = 0;
```

Then hash should behave as you want it to.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Stupid mistake on my end

Answer (score 0):

Because of this `int hash = super.hashCode();` Two different objects have two different `super.hashCode();`.

That's why you get two different hash codes.

But if you don't extend any class you don't have to call `super.hashCode();`
`int hash = 31` is enough.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks so much. Stupid mistake on my end, been a while since I've overridden a hashcode.